# create plots of number of comparisons between Merge Sort and Insertion Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm required to create 2 plots of comparing between Merge Sort and Insertion Sort.

n = input or number of elements in the array that will be sorted
nc = number of comparisons performed by each sorting algorithm.

the first plot shows the results of Merge sort and Insertion Sort using a log × log scale (on the x-axis log(n), on the y-axis log(nc)).

The second plot shows the results of Merge Sort using log(n) x (nc/n) scale (log scale on the x-axis only and the y-axis shows the values of nc/n)

Could someone please explain what the (log(n) x log(nc)) and (log(n) x (nc/n)) scale mean?
I don't understand why we should use the log to create the plots, and what log(n), log(nc), (nc/n) mean in the plots.

Thank you very much and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To get started, here is a [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) explaining what is a logarithmic scale.

So, why would one use logarithms to create the plots? When comparing algorithms, you are usually interested in how good they perform on a wide variety of inputs. It makes sense to measure the performance for just n = 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 instead of the whole range of n = 10, 11, 12, 13, ..., 99999, 100000. This way, you quickly grasp the behavior instead of wasting the time and plot space on hundreds of values like n = 99800, 99801, ..., 99900 which are usually very similar in nature.

Now, what log(n), log(nc), (nc/n) mean in the plots? There are two quantities associated with each axis. The first is the value that is shown on the axis. The second is used to determine spacing. For example, an axis showing n with linear scale will have several points like n = 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 shown on the axis and spaced evenly: points with the same difference in n will have the same distance between them. An axis showing n with logarithmic scale will have some points like n = 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 shown on the axis and spaced evenly: points with the same difference in log(n) will have the same distance between them. Note that the base of the logarithm in this case does not matter: if we change the base, differences which were the same remain the same.

More specifically, a (X=n, Y=nc) log-log plot will be something like this:

- X axis will be for n, and contain five points for n = 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 spaced evenly;
- Y axis will be for nc, and contain seven points for nc = 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 1000000, also spaced evenly;
- You measure the performance for the chosen values of n and put several points (n<sub>i</sub>, nc<sub>i</sub>) on the plot;
- The actual curve is approximated, either by a piecewise linear function between the points or by some smooth curve.